# How to find the element Name="Password" to change the value to my current password

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import *
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import *
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver

usernameStr = '@email.com'
passwordStr = '*******'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://ebill.nationalfuelgas.com/cgi/natfuel-bin/vortex.cgi')
browser.maximize_window()

# fill in username and hit the next button

time.sleep(3)
browser = browser.find_element_by_name("login")
browser.send_keys(usernameStr)
browser.send_keys(Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(5)

# Wait for transition then continue to fill items
```

I am trying to get this code figure out please help

```
password = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
time.sleep(1)
```

I have tried to Tag Name, Name etc and still is not doing much every other code works but except this one.

```
# This code is to login the website
slogin = browser.find_element_by_name("continue" + Keys.ENTER)
```

Snapshot:

[image: View Source]

Comment: thank you very much! @DebanjanB

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to the *Email* and *Password* field using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://ebill.nationalfuelgas.com/cgi/natfuel-bin/vortex.cgi")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.inputfield[alt='Email']"))).send_keys("shadownet96")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.inputfield[alt='Password']").send_keys("shadownet96")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://ebill.nationalfuelgas.com/cgi/natfuel-bin/vortex.cgi")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='inputfield' and @alt='Email']"))).send_keys("shadownet96")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='inputfield' and @alt='Password']").send_keys("shadownet96")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: ebil]